# Python 3: Good location(s) to install own and 3rd party packages?

Tags: python, installation, package

For Python 3.x:

I'd like advice on best directory in which to locate modules that I want to use across multiple projects (and any related factors).  I know about the import statement and PYTHONPATH, and various ways to make any location "work", but I want to be in line with standard practice.

So:

1. Should I be putting my modules in a package in "Pythonxx\Lib\site-packages"?
2. Does the site-packages directory get special treatment, or is it no different than other possible locations for modules?  I'm confused as to whether it has special ".pth" and/or `__init__.py` behavior.
3. To what extent are conventions influenced by what distutils does, which doesn't seem to be really ready for Python 3... and does that mean that I should be attending to some other conventions going forward?
4. What should I make of this: http://docs.python.org/py3k/install/index.html in which "How installation works" seems to claim (in the table) that 'site-packages' is not relevant to Windows, though I see an empty site-packages directory in my Windows Python 3.1 installation.

-- Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, I see the first two answers are related to how to deploy packages (virtualenv and setup.py).  My case is just for working on a single desktop, where I can put generally-used modules where I want manually, and possibly adjust paths manually without "deploying" per se.  Maybe I can be talked into doing things more formally, but at the moment creating an installation for these files seems like overkill.

Comment: Are you planning to accept an answer (see the big tick to the left of each answer)? If not, tell us what extra help you need.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes -- but let your setup.py do it
2. No
3. Why do you think there is a problem?
4. The docs need fixing. The default Python install directory is C:\PythonXY, not C:\Python. The default package install directory is C:\PythonXY\Lib\site-packages.

Comment: 1. Evidently setup.py is part of creating a deployment for some packages.  I'm not wanting to deploy per se... I've added a comment to the question.

Comment: 2. OK
3. Well, I'm having difficulty discerning the current state-of-play in installation software, and whether my "informal" system-wide packages should mimic what installation software, or do something different to stay out of it/their way.
4. Or perhaps "C:\PythonXY\site-packages" ?

Comment: setup.py is all about developers setting up a model/package for distribution/deployment. The final stage of this is when you install the module/etc by doing `....\python setup.py install`. If it's your own module/package, make like a developer. In any case, don't juct copy bunches of files willy-nilly to site-packages.

Comment: On the deployment phase, I understand the rationale for proper deployment (tho I'm struggling to discern from many doc pages what deployment tools are in what state of readiness for Python 3).  However the case in question is more like this -- I want the common module(s) to still be develop-able. Say I have projects A, B and C under development, and all call common module "myutils.py", which is also undergoing revision based on evolving requirements identified in A, B and C.  Is there a favorable place to locate myutils.py?  Maybe site-packages is totally the wrong place for that, fair enough.

Comment: About myutils.py: unit-test it in your development environment. When you are happy that it meets requirements, release a new version and install it. Then test your development versions of a, b, c (no upper case, please).

Answer (score 1):

You might wish to consider setting up a [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), which is the standard way of bundling a set of modules for use across projects and platforms.

Comment: I appreciate this response but... I'm not interested in deployment (at the moment) just using same code on multiple projects on a single desktop machine.  From reading the pypi doc page, virtualenv looks more suited to use cases involving deployment to servers etc, so though I'd heard of virtualenv, it didn't seem to be helpful to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Coincidentally, it's the anniversary of my asking this question.  Though the respondents attempted to be helpful, I ended up investigating this issue in substantially more depth. That led to notes which I posted here: [Python- Organization for common modules](http://grahamwideman.wikispaces.com/Python-+Organization+for+common+modules).
Also some issue reports at python.org (same user name), and some revisions to their documentation.  I hope that helps others who are similarly stumped.

Comment: I'd be interested in your notes, but the link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @A.Donda Those old notes are probably obsolete. It's still about how the import function, and related like sys.path, and how they might apply to the problem at hand -- libraries shared by multiple programs that are all under development in parallel, in an informal programming scenario, not intended for deployment far and wide. IMO there still isn't a good solution to this particular problem. Some related issues were improved (create virtual environment feature is supplied with Python 3.x) or more messy (PEP420 making packages vague -- see https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/97).

Answer (score 0):

[Per-user site-packages directory](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/) is another option. You can try it with:

```
python setup.py install --user
```

Installing to `%APPDATA%\Python\Python32` is much more lightweight than creating a whole new virtualenv. This is what [PyPM](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/) does by default.